# Suppress a row based on a field value

Tags: reporting-services, matrix, reporting, crosstab

I'm presenting data in a matrix (a crosstab). To ensure that all rows are represented I right-joined with a table of the columns that are to appear. This also (expectedly) produces a blank row. Identifying the blank row is easy enough; just test for null in one of the fields. But filtering the data causes a reversion to original behaviour, which is columns only where there is data.

Is there a way to suppress a row? I mean, presumably there is, but I can't seem to find it in help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out myself. There's a "Row Visibility..." dialog. Right-click the row handle.

[image: Invoking Row Visibility dialog]

This produces the dialog.

[image: Row Visibility dialog]

You want to show or hide based on an expression. In this case

```
=Fields!SiteName.Value=""
```

does the trick. Originally I checked for null

```
=IsNothing(Fields!SiteName.Value)
```

but that doesn't work. Somehow it gets converted to an empty string.